# Wordpress Folder in Angular Project - Can We Access the Wordpress Website?

Tags: angular, wordpress

I have an angular application and also WordPress website. My angular website is `http://localhost:4200`. Can I include WordPress folder inside the angular application with the name of folder called blog, Now can I access the WordPress website through the url `http://localhost:4200/blog/`, does it work or not?
And is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this would be to use something like nginx and proxy requests to a specific sub path.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/932628/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-nginx-reverse-proxy for an example of how to do this using `proxy_pass`

Comment: In which file i want to add proxy_pass. I'm not clear with that solution. Can you please tell me clearly?

Comment: In your nginx.conf file or the site level conf file